# Does uglify-js support es6 and above?

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, uglifyjs, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

I am watching this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHifDVw5t_w . And in this video it is mentioned that `uglify-js` does not support es6 and above version of js. But when I try to minify js code(Es6 and above) with the help of `uglify-js`, it is perfectly minify the js file and did not throw any error.

Answer (score 3):

You should rely on [official documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#note) instead of random YouTube videos:

> Note:
>
> - uglify-js supports JavaScript and most language features in ECMAScript.
> - For more exotic parts of ECMAScript, process your source file with transpilers like Babel before passing onto uglify-js.
> - uglify-js@3 has a simplified API and CLI that is not backwards compatible with uglify-js@2.

You should be fine unless you are using features such as [optional chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66619837/211627) that were only recently added to the standard, in which case the module authors simply haven't had enough time to add support.

Comment: Terser's page is misleading in that case, as it says: "uglify-js does not support ES6+." I guess they refer to previous versions, and not to the newest uglify-js@3 (version 3) - but - still misleading. Anyhow, seems that uglify-js@3 indeed supports ES6...

Comment: From my use case, uglify-js 2 notably doesn't support at least `const` and array functions, and I hesitate to rewrite all my scripts to switch to uglify-js 3, IIRC I had to browserify it to be able to use in a broswer and it was not a simple task..